# Get number of users registered on a specific day

Tags: django

I am trying to get number of regisetered users grouped by day but so far failed.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  createdon=models.DateField()
```

the following raw sql works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(day(createdon)),day(createdon) from members_profile where month(createdon)=11 and year(createdon)=2017 GROUP BY day(createdon)
```

The output now is:

```
  1   10
  5    8
```

In ORM, the closest i came was:

```
   Profile.objects.extra({'d':"day(createdon)"}).values('d').annotate(count=Count('id'))

   1 1
   5 1
   5 1
```

But that doesn't surprise it since id is unique field. I instead want to group by 'd', which annotate column complains can not be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDay
from django.db.models import Count
(Profile.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('createdon'))
                .values('day')
                .annotate(count=Count('id'))
                .order_by())
```

Comment: Works like a charm. There is a missing ) after the first annotate tho.

Comment: Cool, and fixed.